# Find Absolute in AVX

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, avx, avx2, absolute-value

In one of the solution, he/she found **abs(inp)** for AVX vectors as,

__m256 sign_bit = _mm256_set1_ps(-0.0f);
__m256 inp_abs = _mm256_andnot_ps(sign_bit, inp);

What's the logic behind it?.

[SSE/AVX: Choose from two __m256 float vectors based on per-element min and max absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415188/sse-avx-choose-from-two-m256-float-vectors-based-on-per-element-min-and-max-a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) represents floating-point numbers with a sign bit, significand and exponent.  The sign bit is set for a negative number and clear for a positive number.  So absolute value can be computed by simply clearing the sign bit of a number.

The number `-0.0f` has significand magnitude and exponent which are all-bits-zero, and negative sign, so its binary representation will have the sign bit set and all other bits clear.  Therefore it can be used as a mask for the sign bit.  The [`_mm256_set1_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_set1_ps&expand=4980) intrinsic broadcasts this 32-bit value to all the elements of a 256-bit vector `sign_bit`, and [`_mm256_andnot_ps(sign_bit, inp)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_andnot_ps&expand=332) computes the bitwise AND of `inp` with the NOT of `sign_bit`, that is `inp & ~sign_bit`, which effectively clears the sign bit of each element and doesn't change anything else.

Comment: Technically, the exponent for 0 is *emin*, −126, per IEEE-754 3.4, item e toward the bottom of the page. The bit string in the field that encodes the exponent is zero. I mention this not because it is particularly important for 0, but it is important for people to understand the distinctions between the values of significands and exponents and the bit strings of the fields that encode them. Keeping this in mind can help people from mistakenly thinking the significand has 23 bits instead of 24, for example.